# XSLT lookup from external xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am aware that there are plenty of questions (and answers) here on the lookup from external xml files via xslt. However, I still haven't got my head around the logic of the key function so I'm having a hard time applying other solutions to my use case.

I have two xml files:

**versA.xml**

```
<TEI>
  <div>
    <l id="A001" corresp="B001">First line of VersA</l>
    <l id="A002" corresp="B002">Second line of VersA</l>
    <l id="A003" corresp="B003">Third line of VersA</l>
  </div>
</TEI>
```

and

**versB.xml**

```
<TEI>
  <div>
    <l id="B001" corresp="A001">First line of VersB</l>
    <l id="B002" corresp="A002">Second line of VersB</l>
    <l id="B003" corresp="A003">Third line of VersB</l>
  </div>
</TEI>
```

The files refer to each other via the `corresp`-attribute.

I'm trying to figure out a xsl stylesheet (**trans.xsl**) that parses **versA.xml**, prints its own text node and then looks up the corresponding text node in **versB.xml**

**trans.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="vB" select="document('versB.xml')/TEI/div/l"/>

<xsl:template match="/TEI/div/l">
I found ID <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> in versA.xml.
How can I get the corresponding node in versB.xml which has the ID <xsl:value-of select="@corresp"/>?
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I can do is output the ids of **versA.xml** and access **versB.xml**. I find it extremely difficult however, to set up an appropriate key function that takes the `corresp` value from **versA.xml** to look up the corresponding id in **versB.xml**

I'd be happy if somebody could explain how this can be achieved.

For compatibility reasons xslt version 1.0 would be preferred.

I have updated my stylesheet according to the suggestions given in the comments. The following gives the desired output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="ref" match="TEI/div/l" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/TEI/div/l">

  <xsl:variable name="corresp" select="@corresp"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/> corresponds to 
  <xsl:for-each select="document('versB.xml')">
     <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', $corresp)"/>
   </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a key with `xsl:key`, giving it a `name` you can choose, using a `match` pattern of the nodes you want to "index", you want to declare the key for, and defining a key value with the `use` attribute, an XPath expression:

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="TEI/div/l" use="@id"/>
```

To use a key you call the `key` function with the name of the declared key as the first argument, the key value as the second argument and, in XSLT 2 or later, the document or subtree you want to search, as the third argument: `key('ref', @corresp, document('versB.xml'))`.

If you are really restricted to XSLT 1 then, with two different documents, as the third argument of the `key` function is not supported, you need to switch the "context document" with `for-each`, for instance:

```
<!-- need to store value of main input document we want to lookup in variable -->
<xsl:variable name="corresp" select="@corresp"/>

<!-- now we change the context document to be able to apply the key function on secondary input -->
<xsl:for-each select="document('versB.xml')">
   <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', $corresp)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Both example uses of the `key` function above assume you make them in the context of an `xsl:template match="/TEI/div/l"` so that `@corresp` selects the value of that attribute of an `l` element in your main input.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my code in my questions above. The key function seems not to work as it output an empty string.

Comment: @AlexW., see the edit, it seems I have misunderstood the relation, if the `corresp` in the first document refers to the `id` in the second then the `use` attribute in the key declaration needs to be `use="@id"`.

Comment: Just to add another difficulty (relevant to my use case): The `<l></l>` text nodes sometimes contain `<note></note>` elements. I can define templates that transform the `<note>`-elements in the main document (**versA.xml**). I don't know, however, how to apply-templates to the 'imported' **versB.xml**.

Comment: @AlexW., please raise that as a separate question unless `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', $corresp)/note"/>` (XSLT 1, needs to be inside of the `for-each` that changed the context document) or `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', $corresp, document('versB.xml'))"/>` (XSLT 2 and later) does not help.