# apply XSL template to element that is selected via key function

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, tei

This is an adapted follow-up question to [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578625/xslt-lookup-from-external-xml-file/60578945?noredirect=1#comment107174346_60578945).

I have got to xml files referring to one another by the `corresp`-attribute.

**main.xml**

```
<body>
  <div type="section">
    <div type="subsection">
      <l id="A01" corresp="B01"><note>First</note> line of A</l>
      <l id="A02" corresp="B02">Second line of A</l>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**to_merge.xml**

```
<body>
  <div type="section">
    <div type="subsection">
      <l id="B01" corresp="A01">First line of B</l>
      <l id="B02" corresp="A02">Second <note>line</note> of B</l>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

My XSL stylesheet **trans.xsl** (created following the kind suggestions by @michael-hor257k and @martin-honnen):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="ref" match="body/div/div/l" use="@id"/>


<xsl:template match="/body">
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//div/div">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
      </html>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="div/div">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="l"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="l">
  <xsl:variable name="corresp" select="@corresp"/>
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
    <td>
      <xsl:for-each select="document('to_merge.xml')">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('ref', $corresp)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
  <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet almost does what I'd like it to do. The produced output:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body><table>
<tr>
<td>
<b>First</b> line of A</td>
<td>First line of B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Second line of A</td>
<td>Second line of B</td>
</tr>
</table></body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I cannot define a template to process the `<note>`-element in the imported document in exactly the same way as the **main.xml**, that is I would like to have `<td>Second <b>line</b> of B</td>` in the last cell of the last row.

Do I have to choose a completely different approach?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is a short-hand for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`, meaning it processes the child nodes of the context node, which in your template is an `l` element.

Inside of the `xsl:for-each select="document('to_merge.xml')"` the context node is the secondary input and the `key` function call `key('ref', $corresp)` selects an `l` element in that document. So you want to `apply-templates` to the child nodes of that `l` element, meaning instead of the `xsl:value-of` you have you want to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', $corresp)/node()"/>`.